# Replace GetInstanceOfClass1()->GetInstanceOfClass2() with extern?

Tags: c++

What will happen if I "shorten" this call:

```
GetInstanceOfClass1()->GetInstanceOfClass2();
```

(where the instance of Class2 is a member of Class1) with a extern function declared in Class1.cpp:

```
extern void GetInstanceOfClass2()
{
   GetInstanceOfClass1()->GetInstanceOfClass2();
}
```

Will the compiler (clang) produce inefficient code? Is that an ugly, bad idea actually?

Comment: May I ask why you make the function `extern "C++"`? In C++, that's the default.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Remark accepted! I was thinking about Objective-C.

Comment: You could look at the assembler output to see if it differs.